# Looping through a paginated api asynchronously

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, pagination, twisted

I'm currently ingesting data through an API that returns close to 100,000 documents in a paginated fashion (100 per page). I currently have some code that roughly functions as follows:

```
while c <= limit:
    if not api_url:
        break

    req = urllib2.Request(api_url)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    f = opener.open(req)
    response = simplejson.load(f)

    for item in response['documents']:
        # DO SOMETHING HERE 
    if 'more_url' in response:
        api_url = response['more_url']
    else:
        api_url = None
        break
    c += 1
```

Downloading the data this way is really slow and I was wondering if there is any way to loop through the pages in an async way. I have been recommended to take a look at [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), but I am not entirely sure how to proceed.

Comment: One straightforward approach is to reuse the connection to the server. I highly recommend using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for everything HTTP related. Also, can you predict the next page token (`more_url` in your case). If you can, the messages could be sent in parallel, wich would speed up the whole operation by quite a lot.

Comment: unfortunately, more_url is not predictable. I will take a look at requests, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is that you do not know up front about what will be read next unless you will call an API. Think of this like, what you can do in parallel?

I do not know how much you can do in parallel and which tasks, but lets try...

some assumptions:
- you can retrieve data from the API without penalties or limits
- data processing of one page/batch can be done independently one from other

what is slow is an IO - so immediately you can split your code to two parallel running tasks - one that will read data, then put it in the queue and continue reading unless hit limit/empty response or pause if queue is full

then second task, that is taking data from queue, and do something with data

so you can call one task from another

other approach is that you have one task, that is calling other one immediately after data is read, so their execution will be running in parallel but slightly shifted

how I'll implement it? as [celery](http://celeryproject.org) tasks and yes [requests](http://python-requests.org)

e.g. the second one:

```
@task
def do_data_process(data):
   # do something with data
   pass

@task
def parse_one_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()

    if 'more_url' in data:
        parse_one_page.delay(data['more_url'])

    # and here do data processing in this task
    do_data_process(data)
    # or call worker and try to do this in other process
    # do_data_process.delay(data)
```

and it is up to you how many tasks you will run in parallel if you will add limits to your code, you can even have workers on multiple machines and have separate queues for `parse_one_page` and `do_data_process`

why this approach, not twisted or async?

because you have cpu-bond data processing (json, then data) and for this is better to have separate processes and celery is perfect with them.

Comment: Thanks Jerzyk's for your detailed answer. I did set up çelery and tried your approach, but i ended up taking a slightly different and easier(IMO) route to solve this. I spun up a process to hit the API and download the json using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to a tmp folder and used the python package [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) to monitor changes to that directory, every time a file was created, i processed it and i was able to complete the whole process (~1000 pages of data) in under 15 mins. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Srinath You can also create a url list , with param  = page number and make multi threaded calls to all urls at the same time , concat the dataframes and merge into one.